# Get relevant sub-category associated with the current product from parent category in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, taxonomy-terms

This is not meant to be a duplicate question, however, it seems that the wordpress.stackexchange forum is quiet on this one... Im hoping someone might help!

The following link of mine refers: [Get only relevant sub-category of category...](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/370983/)

I am busy with a music site. The scenario is the following:

1. A song(WooCommerce product), has a category of "Rock" Rock is a sub-category of "Genre".
2. The Genre category has a number of different sub-categories (Rock, Pop, Classical, etc).
3. These categories were setup while importing products into WooCommerce and my Categories string in my initial import CSV looks like this (I'm using dummy data for development purposes):

`Genre, Genre > Rock, Artist, Artist > Abigail Jay > Hulking Depend Weigh, Album > Hulking Depend Weigh, Year, Year > 2014`

In the above example Rock is a sub-category of Genre.

With the following code I get all the sub-categories listed under "Genre":

```php
global $product;
$terms = get_the_terms($product->get_id(), 'product_cat');
foreach($terms as $term)
{
    if($term->slug == "genre")
    {
        $_id = $term->term_id;
        $_s = $term->slug;
        $_ar = array('parent' => $_id);
        $assoc_categories = get_terms('product_cat', $_ar);
    }
}
```

This is however not correct. What I am trying to do (and not winning with) is to get hold of the relevant sub-category(for example Rock) associated with the current product via php. In other words I need to look which sub-category of Genre is associated with the product.

I am probably missing something small, however this has kept me busy for quite a while now... any help would be greatly appreciated!

---

**EDIT:**

Ok, I have come up with a bit of a round-about way to get what I need and have updated my code as follows:

```php
global $product;
$terms = get_the_terms($product->get_id(), 'product_cat');
$_x = array();
foreach($terms as $term)
{
    if($term->slug == "genre")
    {
        $_id = $term->term_id;
        $_s = $term->slug;
        $_ar = array('parent' => $_id);
        $assoc_categories = get_terms('product_cat', $_ar);
        
        foreach(get_terms('product_cat', $_ar) as $_gt)
        {
            $genre_dict[] = $_gt->name;
        }
    }
    if(in_array($term->name, $genre_dict))
    {
        echo($term->name);
    }
}
```

*A short explanation of the above*:

1. I create an array named `$genre_dict` containing all the sub-categories contained within the category Genre.
2. I then compare `$term->name` with each entry in `$genre_dict` and if a match is found, I output `$term->name`.

Is there perhaps a better way of achieving the same result?

Comment: *"…is to get hold of the the Genre-sub-category(for example Rock) associated with the current product via php"* is unclear and not understandable… Please try to reword your question giving a simple example and telling what you get with your code and what you expect to get with it.

Comment: @LoicTheAztec Thank you for your feedback, I have edited my question and have added some additional info of what I have tried as well. Not sure how to better explain than that...

Comment: You should add your Edit code as an answer as it works…

Comment: I was wondering if there is perhaps a better/ more elegant way of doing it?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I have come up with a bit of a round-about way to get what I need and have updated my code as follows:

```php
global $product;
$terms = get_the_terms($product->get_id(), 'product_cat');
$_x = array();
foreach($terms as $term)
{
    if($term->slug == "genre")
    {
        $_id = $term->term_id;
        $_s = $term->slug;
        $_ar = array('parent' => $_id);
        $assoc_categories = get_terms('product_cat', $_ar);
        
        foreach(get_terms('product_cat', $_ar) as $_gt)
        {
            $genre_dict[] = $_gt->name;
        }
    }
    if(in_array($term->name, $genre_dict))
    {
        echo($term->name);
    }
}
```

*A short explanation of the above*:

1. I create an array named `$genre_dict` containing all the sub-categories contained within the category Genre.
2. I then compare `$term->name` with each entry in `$genre_dict` and if a match is found, I output `$term->name`.

**EDIT**

I have created a more comprehensive bit of code builds an array containing the following:

- Artist Name, ID, Slug >

  - Each Albums Name, ID, Slug, Year, Genre >

    - Each Songs Name, ID, Slug, SKU, Link to a preview of the Track

```php
if((!empty($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] !== 'off') || $_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] == 443)
{
    $GLOBALS['base_href'] = 'https://'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].'/';
}
else
{
    $GLOBALS['base_href'] = 'http://'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].'/';
} // END OF: if((!empty($_SERVER['HTTPS'...
$main_category = get_queried_object();
$main_category_id = $main_category->term_id;
$main_category_name = $main_category->name;
$main_category_slug = $main_category->slug;
foreach(get_terms('product_cat',  $main_category_id) as $term)
{
    if($term->slug == "genre")
    {
        foreach(get_terms('product_cat', ['parent' => $term->term_id]) as $_gt)
        {
            $genre_dict[] = $_gt->name;
        }
    } // END OF: if($term->slug == "genre"...
    if($term->slug == "year")
    {
        foreach(get_terms('product_cat', ['parent' => $term->term_id]) as $_gt)
        {
            $year_dict[] = $_gt->name;
        }
    } // END OF: if($term->slug == "year"...
} // END OF: foreach(get_terms('product_cat',  $sub_category_id...

$_ARTIST_OBJ = 
[
    'artist_id' => $main_category->term_id,
    'artist_name' => $main_category->name,
    'artist_slug' => $main_category->slug
];
foreach(get_terms('product_cat', ['parent' => $main_category_id]) as $sub_category)
{
    
    $sub_category_id = $sub_category->term_id;
    $sub_category_name = $sub_category->name;
    $sub_category_slug = $sub_category->slug;

    $_ARTIST_OBJ['artist_albums'][$sub_category->slug] = 
    [
        'album_id' => $sub_category->term_id,
        'album_name' => $sub_category->name,
        'album_slug' => $sub_category->slug,
        'album_year' => "",
        'album_genre' => "",
        'album_artwork' => $GLOBALS['base_href'].'wp-content/uploads/album_images/'.$sub_category->slug.'.jpg',
        'album_tracks' => []
    ];

    $product_loop = new WP_Query
    (
        [
            'post_type' => 'product',
            'product_cat' => $sub_category_name,
            'field' => $sub_category_id
        ]
    );
    if($product_loop->have_posts())
    {
        while($product_loop->have_posts())
        {
            $product_loop->the_post();
            global $product;
            $_ARTIST_OBJ['artist_albums'][$sub_category->slug]['album_tracks'][$product->get_slug()] = 
            [
                'track_id' => $product->get_id(),
                'track_name' => $product->get_name(),
                'track_slug' => $product->get_slug(),
                'track_sku' => $product->get_sku(),
                'track_preview' => $GLOBALS['base_href'].'wp-content/uploads/audio/samples/'.strtolower(str_replace(array(" ", "-"), "", $product->get_name().$product->get_sku())).'-sample.mp3'
            ];
            foreach(get_the_terms($product->get_id(), 'product_cat') as $term)
            {
                if(in_array($term->name, $genre_dict))
                {
                    $_ARTIST_OBJ['artist_albums'][$sub_category->slug]['album_genre'] = $term->name;
                } // END OF: if(in_array($term->name, $genre_dict...
                if(in_array($term->name, $year_dict))
                {
                    $_ARTIST_OBJ['artist_albums'][$sub_category->slug]['album_year'] = $term->name;
                } // END OF: if(in_array($term->name, $year_dict...
                
            }

        } // END OF: while($product_loop->have_posts(...
    }
    else
    {
        echo("<p>There are no products...</p>");
    } // END OF: if($product_loop->have_posts(...
} // END OF: foreach(get_terms('product_cat', ['parent' => $main_category_id...

print_r($_ARTIST_OBJ);
```

Hopefully this may help another Noob that comes across the same challenge somewhere down the line.